# Host key verification failed [rsync: connection unexpectedly closed]

Tags: ssh, cron, rsync

I have been stuck with a peculiar problem, where rsync command is not running when it is executed through crontab.
Below is the code :

```
#!/bin/sh -x
PATH=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools:/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:~/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-6/bin
/bin/sh /etc/profile
MyUSER="root"       # USERNAME
MyPASS="password"         # PASSWORD
MyHOST="localhost"  # Hostname
Password="" #Linux Password

MYSQL="$(which mysql)"
if [ -z "$MYSQL" ]; then
echo "Error: MYSQL not found"
exit 1
fi
MYSQLADMIN="$(which mysqladmin)"
if [ -z "$MYSQLADMIN" ]; then
    echo "Error: MYSQLADMIN not found"
    exit 1
fi
CHOWN="$(which chown)"
if [ -z "$CHOWN" ]; then
    echo "Error: CHOWN not found"
    exit 1
fi
CHMOD="$(which chmod)"
if [ -z "$CHMOD" ]; then
    echo "Error: CHMOD not found"
    exit 1
fi

GZIP="$(which gzip)"
if [ -z "$GZIP" ]; then
    echo "Error: GZIP not found"
    exit 1
fi
CP="$(which cp)"
if [ -z "$CP" ]; then
    echo "Error: CP not found"
    exit 1
fi
MV="$(which mv)"
if [ -z "$MV" ]; then
    echo "Error: MV not found"
    exit 1
fi
RM="$(which rm)"
if [ -z "$RM" ]; then
    echo "Error: RM not found"
    exit 1
fi
RSYNC="$(which rsync)"
if [ -z "$RSYNC" ]; then
    echo "Error: RSYNC not found"
    exit 1
fi

MYSQLBINLOG="$(which mysqlbinlog)"
if [ -z "$MYSQLBINLOG" ]; then
    echo "Error: MYSQLBINLOG not found"
    exit 1
fi
# Get data in dd-mm-yyyy format
NOW="$(date +"%d-%m-%Y-%T")"

DEST="/home/db-backup"
mkdir $DEST/Increment_backup.$NOW
LATEST=$DEST/Increment_backup.$NOW
$MYSQLADMIN -u$MyUSER -p$MyPASS flush-logs
newestlog=`ls -d /usr/local/mysql/data/mysql-bin.?????? | sed 's/^.*\.//' | sort -g | tail -n 1`
echo $newestlog
for file in `ls /usr/local/mysql/data/mysql-bin.??????`
do
        if [ "/usr/local/mysql/data/mysql-bin.$newestlog" != "$file" ]; then
     echo $file
     echo $Password | sudo -S $CHMOD 0777 $file
         #sudo $MYSQLBINLOG $file>$file.$NOW.sql
     $CP "$file" $LATEST
     #$RM "$file.$NOW.sql"
     #$MV $file.sql.gz /$LATEST
        fi
done
for file1 in `ls $LATEST/mysql-bin.??????`
do
 $MYSQLBINLOG $file1>$file1.$NOW.sql 
 $GZIP -9 "$file1.$NOW.sql"     
 $RM "$file1"
done
 $RSYNC -v -e ssh $LATEST abc@192.168.1.9:/home/rsync-backup/
#FILE=$LATEST/"mysql-bin.??????"
#$MYSQLBINLOG $FILE>$FILE.$NOW.sql
#$GZIP -f "$FILE.$NOW.sql"
pwd
```

Rsync happens when the code is run manually, but fails when it is run through crontab. Rest of the commands are working fine. From the logs I got this information:

```
Host key verification failed.^M
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]
```

Comment: It can be a permission problem. Are you running the cron job under same user when running the script manually??

Comment: What means "fails"? Can you show exact output in that case?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gelraen. Fails means the script is running fine when executed manually, but in crontab nothing happens, no transfer of files, etc.

Comment: Please show us your crontab entry. Additionally make sure you have error logging there also like this: '...script.sh >>/tmp/logfile 2>&1'

Comment: */1 * * * * /home/db-backup/incrementaltest.sh>>/home/rsynclst 2>&1 is my cron entry. I'm getting this error **Host key verification failed.^M rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender] rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all....got the answer finally. When I was running it manually I was running as a local user. But, on cron I was running it as root user, for which ssh key was not generated. I did `ssh-keygen` and created the keys. Now it works.

Answer (score 2):

`ssh` (which `rsync` executes) doesn't trust the host key of the server, and since there is no interactive terminal to prompt the user it simply fails. The cause is probably that `ssh` is looking at a different `known_hosts` file when running under cron that when you execute it manually.

If the cronjob runs as a different user to you, you need to manually accept the host key by doing something like this:

```
sudo -u cronuser HOME=/home/cronuser ssh abc@192.168.1.9
```

If the cronjob is running as your user then `$HOME` probably isn't set correctly. Specify that explicitly in the crontab:

```
HOME=/home/vishu
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply mgorven. I'm running this script as a root. The script runs with rsync when executed manually, but is failing on crontab, should I fix this with some environment variable.

Comment: You could add the option `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` to the ssh command in your script.

Comment: @Vishu Try setting `HOME=/root` in the crontab. Are there any prompts about SSH when running the script manually?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar error. This solved my problem:
ssh to host machine where data is migrated with rsync. After which the host IP was Permanently added to list of known hosts.

Next I ran the same rsync command, and it executed just fine!